# How to pass the props value from the other sibling components in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have question regarding sending clicked value to the first sibling components and I will send the props value to the second siblings is that possible?

I have module where when I click the Category Items to the first siblings the Products on the second sibling will change based on the category name that I click on the first sibling.

**Here is my Parent Components:**

```
 function BuyerCategoryPage(props) {
    

    return (
        <div>
               
                <CategorySlider />



                <CategoryProducts/>
          

        </div>
    )
}

export default BuyerCategoryPage
```

**First Sibling CategorySlider.js:**

```
const HandleChangeProductCat = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    // send the value to the second sibling
}

return (
    
    <div>
        
        <Container fluid>
            <Slider style={{paddingTop:20, margin: '0 auto'}} {...settings}>
                {
                    SlideData.map((data) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={data.id} >
                                <div className="sliderDataCategory">
                                    <h6>
                                        <Container>
                                            <Row>
                                                <Col md={3}>
                                                    <img className="img-fluid" src={data.cat_image}  /> 
                                                </Col>
                                                <Col >
                                                    <label onClick={() => HandleChangeProductCat(data.cat_title)}>{data.cat_title}</label>
                                                </Col>
                                            </Row>
                                        </Container>
                                    </h6>
                                
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </Slider>
        </Container>
        
    </div>
)
```

**Second Sibling CategoryProducts.js**

```
function CategoryProducts(props) {
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the "sibling" components? What is the user interaction between them? Is the user navigating from the first to the second component? Are you just wanting to update some global state from the first and have the second "see" the change? You can [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the closest common ancestor and pass down props to each, use the [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), or a global state management library like Redux.

Comment: @DrewReese you are correct I just want to update some global state from the first and have the second see the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to lift state up into the `BuyerCategoryPage` component and pass an "onChange" handler to `CategorySlider` and the state value to `CategoryProducts`

```
function BuyerCategoryPage(props) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(); // common state

  return (
    <div>      
      <CategorySlider onChange={setState} /> // pass updater function
      <CategoryProducts value={state} /> // pass state value
    </div>
  );
}
```

CategorySlider

```
const handleChangeProductCat = (value) => {
  console.log(value);
  props.onChange(value); // invoke callback and pass new value
}
```

CategoryProducts

```
function CategoryProducts({ value }) { // access the passed value
  // use the `value` prop as necessary 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
function Example() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");

    const onClick = (someValue) => {
        setValue(someValue);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <First onClick={onClick} />
            <Second value={value} />
        </div>
    )
}

function First(props) {
    const onClick = () => {
        props.onClick((new Date()).toString());
    }
    return (
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} value="Click me" />
    )
}

function Second(props) {
    return (
        <div>{props.value}</div>
    )
}
```